# Is Linux SPARSEMEM memory model really sparse?

Tags: c, linux, memory, memory-management, linux-kernel

I am trying to understand how Linux `SPARSEMEM` memory model works. As I understand, when `SPARSEMEM_VMEMMAP` is set, there is a second mapping that 'glues' the  mem_maps from different (possibly disconnected) sections, such that mapping between `PFN` and `page` struct is continuous. So far so good.

Question is, if physical memory does have holes, then mapping from `PFN/page` to physical address should require some customized mapping, rather than simple linear algebra, is that correct?

But in the following code (kernel 5.3), it does seem simple math:

```
/include/asm-generic/memory_model.h
#define __phys_to_pfn(paddr)    PHYS_PFN(paddr)
/include/linux/pfn.h
#define PFN_PHYS(x) ((phys_addr_t)(x) << PAGE_SHIFT)
/include/linux/types.h
typedef u64 phys_addr_t;
```

Does this mean the physical address space still needs to be continous and NO holes allowed? Or did I miss something here? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There's a good summary of how `SPARSEMEM` works [here](https://lwn.net/Articles/134804/).

> Sparsemem uses an array to provide different pfn_to_page()
>   translations for each SECTION_SIZE area of physical memory.  This is
>   what allows the mem_map[] to be chopped up.

Comment: thanks, I guess I understand how/why pfn_to_page() works, but do not understand why __phys_to_pfn() works the way it is - how can it be a continuous mapping if actual physical memory has holes?